# Resize and crop image into square with white background - using GD

Tags: php, caching, thumbnails, gdlib

I've got a script which caches images from an external feed and stores them in a directory on my server when the image is viewed on site.

At the moment it is working great - storing the original image on my server and also creating two additional thumbnails, with their widths re-sized at 300px and 150px.

I'd like to change this slightly so that the following occurs:

1. Full/Original image is stored on server (as normal)
2. Both a **square** 300x300px & 150x150px .jpg thumbnail are created

However, is it possible, so that once the image width/height is resized, the additional canvas width/height is then added to make it completely square? I guess one of the issues here is determining if the image is a 'portrait' or 'landscape' first?

Also, currently I'm getting a black background with transparent PNG images. Is there any way to overcome this and fill the background with white instead?

Thank you very much for any help!! :)

**Here is the code which is doing the resizing (imageCache.php):**

```
<?php
  function cacheFetch($url,$size,$age)
  {
// directory in which to store cached files, must be writable by PHP
$cacheDir = "cache/";
// cache filename constructed from MD5 hash of URL
$filename = $cacheDir.md5($url);
// append size to filename if not 0
if ($size) $filename .= "_".$size;
// default to fetch the file
$fetch = true;
// but if the file exists, don't fetch if it is recent enough
if (file_exists($filename))
{
  $fetch = (filemtime($filename) < (time()-$age));
}
// fetch the file if required
if ($fetch)
{
  if (substr($url,0,4)=="http")
  {
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if (strlen($data))
    {
      $fp = fopen($filename,"w");
      fwrite($fp,$data);
      fclose($fp);
      $error = false;
    }
    else
    {
      $error = true;
    }
  }
  else
  {
    copy($url,$filename);
    $error = false;
  }
}
// return the filename only if wget did not fail
if (!$error)
{
  if ($size)
  {
    $src = file_get_contents($filename);
    $oldImage = imagecreatefromstring($src);
    $oldX = imagesx($oldImage);
    $oldY = imagesy($oldImage);
    if ($oldX && $oldY)
    {
      $newX = $size;
      $xFactor = ($newX / $oldX);
      $newY = intval($oldY * $xFactor);
      $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newX,$newY);
      imagecopyresized($newImage, $oldImage, 0,0,0,0, $newX, $newY, $oldX, $oldY);
      imagejpeg($newImage,$filename);
    }
  }
  return $filename;
}
else
{
  // as an error occured, delete the empty file so it is retried next time
  unlink($filename);
  // return false
  return false;
}
}
require("includes/common.php");

$id = $_GET["id"];

$size = $_GET["size"];

$sql = "SELECT image_url FROM `".$config_databaseTablePrefix."products` WHERE id='".database_safe($id)."'";
if (database_querySelect($sql,$rows))
{
$src = $rows[0]["image_url"];

$src = cacheFetch($src,$size,604800);

$img = file_get_contents($src);

header("Content-Type: image");

print $img;
  }
?>
```

and here is the .htaccess bit with sizes:

```
RewriteRule ^fullimage/(.*).jpg$ imageCache.php?id=$1&size=0 [L]
RewriteRule ^smallimage/(.*).jpg$ imageCache.php?id=$1&size=150 [L]
RewriteRule ^mediumimage/(.*).jpg$ imageCache.php?id=$1&size=300 [L]
```

---

EDIT: Re-worked code:

```
if ($size)
{
    $src = file_get_contents($filename);
    $oldImage = imagecreatefromstring($src);
    $oldX = imagesx($oldImage);
    $oldY = imagesy($oldImage);
    if ($oldX && $oldY)
    {
      $color = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 255,255,255);  //The three parameters are R,G,B
  imagefilledrectangle ($newImage, 0, 0, $newX,  $newY,$color);
      $size = max($newX,$newY);
      $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newX,$newY);
      imagecopyresized($newImage, $oldImage, ($size-$newX)/2,($size-$newY)/2,0,0, $newX, $newY, $oldX, $oldY);  //Just the coordinates was changed
      imagejpeg($newImage,$filename);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I will not add my sugestions to your code, because its is too complicated. SO just the hints.

#### 1. How to make resised image square?

Obviously, we must create square of size of bigger dimension of original image. Here I assume the image has already been resized.

```
$resized = /*We hae resized image downloaded from the site [note1]*/;
$size = max(imagesx($resized), imagesy($resized)); //Make the square so the thumbnail fits in it
$thumbNail = imagecreate($size, $size);  //Square.
imagecopy($thumbNail, 
          ($size-imagesx($resized))/2,   //Put the image in the middle of the square
          ($size-imagesy($resized))/2, 
          0,
          0,
          imagesx($resized),
          imagesy($resized)  
);
```

**[note1]** Alternativelly, you can just compute dimensions to make $size and copyresize image on the square. This will be faster, but is more complicated to make pseudocode for it.

#### 2. How to change background of new images

This is no real mystery - you just [draw rectangle](http://cz.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefilledrectangle.php) over whole image:

```
$color = imagecolorallocate($thumbNail, 255,255,255);
imagefilledrectangle ($thumbNail, 0, 0, imagesx($thumbNail),  imagesy($thumbNail),$color);
```

You can even have a transparent background:

```
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($thumbNail, 255,255,255,127);
imagealphablending($thumbNail, false);  //[note2]
imagefilledrectangle ($thumbNail, 0, 0, imagesx($thumbNail),  imagesy($thumbNail),$color);
imagealphablending($thumbNail, true);  //If you use it
```

**[note2]** Turn off blending, because `transparent`+`black` = `black` again

#### 3. Code related to answer

First the resizing, copying. In the original code, we have the computed new height and width in `$newX` and `$newY`. I will use theese as of the new image sizes.

```
$size = max($newX,$newY);
$newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($size, $size);
imagecopyresized($newImage, $oldImage, ($size-$newX)/2,($size-$newY)/2,0,0, $newX, $newY, $oldX, $oldY);  //Just the coordinates was changed
```

Then he background. Obviously, you should firs set the background, then copy the image. However, I'm separating theese steps so you can see what function does what.

```
 $newImage = imagecreatetruecolor($newX,$newY);
 $color = imagecolorallocate($newImage, 255,255,255);  //The three parameters are R,G,B
 imagefilledrectangle ($newImage, 0, 0, $newX,  $newY,$color);
```

Comment: Wow - thank you so much for taking the time to help me. I probably should have mentioned that I'm a real newbie to this. With that in mind, is there anywhere I could learn where to put this code in context with my original script? For example would I need to REPLACE the current " imagecopyresized " with your " imagecopy " code? Thanks again :)

Comment: As I have mentioned in note1, you it is much more handy to do resizing and copying to square in one step. I will add more specific example to your code, using your variables.

Comment: Okay so I've put the re-worked code in above to show you how I've put it together but it doesn't seem to working. Have I put it together incorrectly?

Comment: I posted it in the 'question' space as it was too many chars for here...sorry.

Comment: I don't like to be mean, but I have strong suspicion, you didn't think about or even read the code. You are changing the image before it is actually defined.

Comment: That's okay, your not being mean. I'm just completely new to this so it's a mistake. I'm not even sure where the image is 'defined' to be honest.

Comment: I edited your post to make the code correct. You didn't aprove my edit - ergo you cannot see it.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I'm completely new to StackOverflow too so didn't even see the notification! Thanks, your solution is working really nicely in terms of sizing and cropping, however the black is still showing where the canvas has been resized?

Comment: Just read about 'imagefill' - would it be appropriate to use that here and where would it fit in within the code?

Comment: Okay - I did it with: imagefill($newImage,0,0,$color);

Thanks very much for all your time and help!! :)

Comment: Imagefill is much less effective. Doing `imagefilledrectangle ($newImage, 0, 0, imagesx($newImage),  imagesy($newImage),$color);` will cost you nothing but will improve performance. Where the `fill` function recursivelly fills pixel by pixel, the rectangle algorythm is faster.